# Sequalize get nearest location get point

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How to get the nearest location, geo point using sequalize,

```
  var Address = sequelize.define('Address', {
    address: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    house: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    landmark: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    type: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
    location: {type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT')},
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
const distance = sequelize.fn('ST_Distance',
    sequelize.cast(sequelize.fn('ST_SetSRID', sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', yourLongitude, yourLatitude), 4326), 'geography'),
    sequelize.cast(sequelize.fn('ST_SetSRID', 'location', 4326), 'geography'));

  Address.findOne({
    order: [[distance, 'ASC']],
    raw: true,
  });
```

So, 'distance' should be a number and show the distance between your location and some object in DB. Sorted from min to max and get the first one.

Comment: I am getting this error.
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that co
rresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GEOGRAPHY), CAST(ST_SetSRID('location', 4326) AS GEOGRAPHY))
 ASC LIMIT 1' at line 1